# How to parse web service data to windows phone 8.0 pivot app MainViewModel?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, httpclient

I'm new to C# windows phone programming. 
I've question related to pivot template app in windows phone 8.0

How could I configure Pivot template app using HttpClient Data ?

I've this http request and can get response as well. This working fine..

```
public async static Task<List<MyData>> GetWebserviceData()
{
       HttpClient = new HttpClient();
       string response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://xxxx/xxx/xxx");

       List<MyData> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List< MyData >>(response);

       return data;
}
```

I want to parse this data to pivot app -> MainViewModel -> LoadData().

```
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public MainViewModel()
            {
                this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// A collection for ItemViewModel objects.
            /// </summary>
            public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; private set; }

            private string _sampleProperty = "Sample Runtime Property Value";
            /// <summary>
            /// Sample ViewModel property; this property is used in the view to display its value using a Binding
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public string SampleProperty
            {
                get
                {
                    return _sampleProperty;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (value != _sampleProperty)
                    {
                        _sampleProperty = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChanged("SampleProperty");
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Sample property that returns a localized string
            /// </summary>
            public string LocalizedSampleProperty
            {
                get
                {
                    return AppResources.SampleProperty;
                }
            }



            /// <summary>
            /// Creates and adds a few ItemViewModel objects into the Items collection.
            /// </summary>
            public void LoadData()
            {
                // This Sample data; want to replace with real data which is return from GetWebserviceData()

                this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID ="1", LineOne = "runtime one", LineTwo = "Maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum", LineThree = "Facilisi faucibus habitant inceptos interdum lobortis nascetur pharetra placerat pulvinar sagittis senectus sociosqu" });
                this.Items.Add(new ItemViewModel() { ID = "2", LineOne = "runtime two", LineTwo = "Dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus", LineThree = "Suscipit torquent ultrices vehicula volutpat maecenas praesent accumsan bibendum dictumst eleifend facilisi faucibus" });


            }


        }
    }
```

can any one help me.. Thank you..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the LoadData function in the following manner:

```
public async void LoadData()
{
    var response = await GetWebserviceData();
    foreach(var item in response)
    {
     this.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear JGPhilip, yes I tried this and it executes without error, but data not binding. Only UI is loading without data. What can be the possible issue?

Comment: Make sure that the LoadData function is awaited in the code behind of the aforementioned page.